# ColdFusion cfform radio button

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10

I want to add every unique element from my main query to ORIGINAL_SPR_LIST. However, sometime there are element that have same PSPR so I do another query to find their different SPR and show them to user in different radio buttons and have user choose one of them and add to ORIGINAL_SPR_LIST. I am not sure how to check which SPR radio button is selected?

```
<loop query = "main>
      <CFIF ListContains(form.ORIGINAL_SPR_LIST,SPR_ID)> <CFOUTPUT>#SPR_ID#<BR></CFOUTPUT>
      <CFELSE> 

           <CFQUERY DataSource="#REQUEST.DSN#" Name="SPR_MULT_PRODUCT">
            SELECT
              COUNT(*) AS COUNT
            FROM
              #DETSVIEW_SEARCH.DETSVIEW_NAME#
            WHERE
              #PSPR_ID# = PARENT_SPR_ID
          </cfquery>

          <CFIF SPR_MULT_PRODUCT.COUNT GT 0>
                <cfform>
                <CFOUTPUT> Please choose a SPR ID <BR> </CFOUTPUT>
                <CFLOOP query="SPR_MULT_PRODUCT">
                    <CFOUTPUT><cfinput type="radio" name="SPRID" value="#SPR_ID#">#SPR_ID#<br></CFOUTPUT>
                </cfloop>
                <input type="submit">
                </cfform>
          <CFELSE><CFOUTPUT>#SPR_ID#<BR></CFOUTPUT>
          <CFSET ORIGINAL_SPR_LIST = ListAppend(ORIGINAL_SPR_LIST,SPR_ID)>
          </cfif>

      </CFIF>

    </cfloop>
```

Comment: Do yourself a favor, don't use `cfform` and the related tags. There is no advantage to using them. Use regular HTML `form` and form elements. You will thank me later. Also, stop putting your tags in upper case....that is for n00bs :D

Answer (score 2):

when you submit the form look at the value of `form.sprid` that will tell you which radio button was selected.

A few things to note, unless you're outputting a variable you don't need `cfoutput` tags. This code does not need a `cfoutput` to work

```
<CFOUTPUT> Please choose a SPR ID <BR> </CFOUTPUT>
```

It also doesn't appear you are using anything that you would need `cfform` for, so don't use it. Use plain HTML forms and even if you need to do some sort of validation, write it yourself rather than relying on `cfform`